Test Jest Render Cokies
I want to render my test page.test of NotificationPage to check if it contains a title but when I run the test it fails and the following appears:
throw new Error("Invariant: cookies() expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available.");


Error: Invariant: cookies() expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available.
at cookies (C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - fempa.es\Desktop\inter\proyectos\intec-web-companion\node_modules\next\src\client\components\headers.ts:41:11)
at getSession (C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - fempa.es\Desktop\inter\projects\intec-web-companion\src\context\lib.ts:68:47)
at getNotifications (C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - fempa.es\Desktop\inter\proyectos\intec-web-companion\src\actions\getNotifications.ts:13:47)
at NotificationsPage (C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - fempa.es\Desktop\inter\proyectos\intec-web-companion\src\app\home\notifications\page.tsx:22:55)
at renderWithHooks

My code is:
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import NotificationsPage from '../../app/home/notifications/page'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';


 
describe('Notifications', () => {

   it('renders the notifications text correctly', async () => {
   render(<NotificationsPage />);
    
    // Wait for the text "Notifications" to be in the document
    await waitFor(() => {
     expect(screen.getByText(/Notifications/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
     });
 });

  /* it('displays the spinner correctly while loading', () => {
   render(<Page />);

   // Search for the spinner by class. Adjust this based on how your spinner is rendered.
   const spinnerElement = screen.getByClass('spinner');
        
   // Check if the spinner is present in the document
   expect(spinnerElement).toBeInTheDocument();
   }); */

});

try downloading a dependency called js-cookie:
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import NotificationsPage from '../../app/home/notifications/page'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

// Mock useRouter:
jest.mock("next/navigation", () => ({
  useRouter() {
   return {
     prefetch: () => null
   };
 }
}));

jest.mock('js-cookie', ()=> jest.fn())
 
describe('Notifications', () => {

   beforeEach(() => {
     // Set the necessary cookies for the test
   Cookies.set('token', 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9...');
   Cookies.set('userId', '');
   Cookies.set("Idea-bfbfa616",'')
   Cookies.set("_ga",'')
   Cookies.set("_ga_8Q63TH4CSL",'')
   Cookies.set("hf-chat",'')
   Cookies.set("next-auth.callback-url",'')
   Cookies.set("next-auth.csrf-token",'')
   });

     it('renders the notifications text correctly', async () => {
         render(<NotificationsPage />);
    
         // Wait for the text "Notifications" to be in the document
         await waitFor(() => {
           expect(screen.getByText(/Notifications/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
         });
       });

     /* it('displays the spinner correctly while loading', () => {
         render(<Page />);

         // Search for the spinner by class. Adjust this based on how your spinner is rendered.
         const spinnerElement = screen.getByClass('spinner');
        
         // Check if the spinner is present in the document
         expect(spinnerElement).toBeInTheDocument();
     }); */

});

I tried with js-cookies but it doesn't work since in order to go to home I need a token that is saved in cookies to work`
